# GoogleMaps: Custom Cluster icon (background) is sometimes glitching if rendered

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I have custom renderer for clusters using on GoogleMap in my app. It has custom drawable background and even number textview is custom layout with my own font and size.

It is working perfectly but sometimes map will not render cluster at all and instead of my custom layout its some weird white-colored circle with semitransparent background and default font. I don't use that kind of layout or drawable for clusters or markers so I don't know from where it is coming from. When I zoom in and then zoom out again, sometimes it is corrected and re-rendered to my drawable.

Here is code:

```
private val stationMarkers = mutableListOf<StationMarkerSettings>()

    inner class StationMarkerRender(private val context: Context, map: GoogleMap, clusterManager: ClusterManager<StationMarker>)
        : DefaultClusterRenderer<StationMarker>(context, map, clusterManager) {

        private val mClusterIconGenerator = IconGenerator(context)

        //TextView displaying number - centered
        private fun makeSquareTextView(context: Context): ViewGroup {
            return (CustomResources.inflateLayout(
                LayoutInflater.from(context),
                R.layout.station_marker_cluster_text,
                null
            ) as ViewGroup)
        }

        override fun onBeforeClusterRendered(
            cluster: Cluster<StationMarker>,
            markerOptions: MarkerOptions
        ) {
            super.onBeforeClusterRendered(cluster, markerOptions)
            mClusterIconGenerator.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.station_pin_cluster))
            mClusterIconGenerator.setContentView(makeSquareTextView(context))
            val icon = mClusterIconGenerator.makeIcon(java.lang.String.valueOf(cluster.size))
            markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(icon))
        }

        override fun onBeforeClusterItemRendered(item: StationMarker, mo: MarkerOptions) {
            stationMarkers.add(StationMarkerSettings(item, mo))
            mo.icon(bitmapDescriptorFromVector(activity, R.drawable.station_pin_unselected)).anchor(anchorU, 1f)
        }

        override fun shouldRenderAsCluster(cluster: Cluster<StationMarker>): Boolean {
            return cluster.size > 1
        }

        override fun getColor(clusterSize: Int): Int {
            return ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.white)
        }

    }
```

Result:

[image]